# Triplet paradox

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, reference-frames

The situation is:

1. A stay at a station
2. B,C board the same train that moving away from the station
3. while the train moving away C start moving inside the train in the opposite direction as such A sees C stationary
4. When the train moving back to the station C which is still on the train, moving in the opposite direction as such A sees C stationary

Question:

When train moves back to the station, who gets older or younger than who?

Comment: Are they moving with speed of light? for @krack_jack

Comment: 1)  The question is ambiguous.  "When the train gets back to the station" --- do you mean the part of the train with B on it or the part with C on it?"  2)  Once you've decided what question you want to ask, draw the spacetime diagram and the answer will be obvious.

Comment: When does C reverse direction?  At the same time the train reverses direction according to C, or at the same time the train reverses direction according to B?  Or at some other time?

Answer (score 1):

Draw a spacetime diagram.

If time goes vertically then the worldline of A is a vertical line because the station is inertial.

C also has a vertical worldline since C always moves to oppose the train. If the train is a glass train A and C are literally next to each, its like if you had stairs next to an escalator. Someone can stand on the stairs and talk to someone going the "wrong way" on the escalator so that they both stay at the same height.

So A and C both have vertical (straight) worldlines, both move inertially, and both age the most amount possible between the two events.

B sits or stands on the train. So the worldline of B goes to the right then left. And just like the twin paradox, this one ages less because of the length of the non straight non inertial path has less proper time between the same events.

Comment: Are A and C both really inertial? C is not floating in the air while boarding the train. It also experience acceleration to compensate while the train moving back and forth.

Comment: @PpbPpb No, it isn't experiencing acceleration. You explicitly said that A sees C be stationary. So C is experiencing an equal and opposite force as what the train would exert on it. That is *how* it manages to move the opposite way as the train. Just like with the escalator, you walk up on the downwards traveling escalator, so you actually stay at rest. You only have motion relative to the escalator, and that is moving, and if you get it right, you are stationary. It's like when you pull a tablecloth out from under a plate that stays put. There is relative motion, but the plate is stationary

Answer (score -2):

You are asking Special Relativity to answer questions about scenarios it is unable to describe. Special relativity is a theory of inertial frames of reference; frames of reference moving at constant velocity.

Lets imagine we are person A. Person C steps onto a train but does not move relative to us. He is stationary and is therefore in the same inertial frame as us. Neither person A nor person C will see anything different. The fact that C was inside of a moving train makes no difference if his velocity relative to the station was zero due to his motion within the train.

Person B, however, has travelled away at the speed of the train and then returned. This is the classic Twin Paradox and is resolved because the scenario is not symmetric. Person B has had to accelerate upto the speed of the train, reverse his velocity to return and then deaccelerate to a stop whilst person A has remained stationary. If both person A and B were holding a pendulum, person A's pendulum would remain stationary whilst person B's would hang at an angle. You can absolutely determine which person has undergone acceleration and crucially, both person A and B will agree on who has experienced an acceleration and who has not.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in this scenario that Special Relativity is "unable to describe".

Comment: you mean when the train comes back B is younger than A and C is equal A. How about B and C? as C moving away from B so when C comes back should C is younger than B?